# JSP - Call a function

Tags: jsp, button, onclick, function-call

I have a Button and a function which displays some data.
I want to call the function on button click. The data needs to be displayed on the same page. I don't want a page forward. And also want to avoid JavaScript.
What should I do?
Here is the code-

```
<form >
Number of jobs: <select name="jobs">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
</select><br>

Number of PE:<select name="process">
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
</select>
<input type=submit value="Submit" onClick=check(x,y)>
</form>
 </text1>


 void check(int x, int y)
{
<jsp:include page="table" > 
   <jsp:param name="jobs"  value=x/>
  <jsp:param name="process"  value=y/>
  </jsp:include>
}
```

I want to call the function check() on button click(submit). Plus I want to send the values selected in the dropdown list as arguments to the function.

Comment: Is with possible with Javascript?

Comment: Yes.. Provide code and some more details

Comment: I have added my code. Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont want a page forward. And also want to avoid javascript.

I think opting out both can't be possible.

You use `jQuery/Ajax` call to display data on the same page without submitting it.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
      function getData() {
          var dataToBeSent  = {
            param1 : $("#jobs").val() ,
            param2: $("#process").val()
            }; // you can change parameter name

          $.ajax({
                url : 'getDataServlet', // Your Servlet mapping or JSP(not suggested)
                data :dataToBeSent, 
                type : 'POST',
                dataType : 'html', // Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.
                success : function(response) {
                    $('#outputDiv').html(response); // create an empty div in your page with some id
                },
                error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
      }

});
```

HTML From Your Example:

```
Number of jobs: <select name="jobs" id="jobs">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
</select><br>

Number of PE:<select name="process" id="process">
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
</select>
<input type=submit value="Submit" onClick=getData();>
```

Comment: Another related Question. How to Display an image. I have a servlet that returns an image. $('#outputDiv').html(response); This is not working. What changes do i have to make?

Comment: @Sourav048: You should post it as another question.